# Can I use the following sentences?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Not sure if all-out can be used in this meaning

I will give all-out of me. 
Such as I will try to do the best of me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I will give all-out of me" is not a natural construction. There are two idioms you seem to be combining here: one is to **[go all out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+all+out)**, and the other is to **[give something your all](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+something+your+all)**. They both mean that you'll try your hardest or best.

So a more natural version could be

> "I will go all out [to do x]"

or

> "I will give [the task] my all"

or

> "I will give my all [to do(ing) x]"

Comment: A third variation is *I will give all of me.*